# Label each plot using ggpubr - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I aranged a set of R plots into one using ggarange, How can I label them A,B and C at the top left of each subplot?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


# default ggplot2 theme
P1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point()

P2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point()

P3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point()
 

ggarrange(P1, P2, P3,  ncol=3, nrow=1, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *labels*:

```
ggarrange(P1, P2, P3,  labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
          ncol = 3, nrow = 1, 
          common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

[image]